# Missing a temporary folder error while uploading media WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I am facing a Missing a temporary folder error when I am uploading media to my WordPress site.
I tried following the steps [Here](https://support.fastwebhost.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/322/26/wordpress-is-giving-error-missing-a-temporary-folder--while-uploading-imagemedia) but no luck. I also tried changing  permission of tmp folder which is in wp-content folder to 777 and adding it in the wp-config.php file `define('WP_TEMP_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content/temp/');` but still I get the same error. I even tried to move the  tmp folder to the root of the project but it didn't work either.